# "Dummy Image" placeholder for webpage

Tags: html, placeholder, typesetting

When developing a web page/application, I often don't have all the data right upfront. Sometimes I need to put dummy text and images in places to get the overall feel of how its going to look. For dummy text, I can use [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) to generate such junk text. But how can I do something similar with images?

Comment: As far as I can think of, you should be asking *"what can I do"* in stackoverflow... Of course you can answer it by yourself once you have a solution. This is like, I opened a question to see whether I can be of any help, and you're asking me "what can you do" like it's my problem and you're offering a solution.

Comment: @TJ You, as I, have enough reps and knowledge to do such edit, so why not do that? .. (this time I did it)

Comment: I am not sure changing someones post into something else with my reputation power is the right think to do, so I shared my opinion.

Comment: @TJ I definitely agree one should not change it to something else, but I thought changing the pronouns from _you_ to _I_ were okay.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Lorem Ipsum, theres this one: [Lorem Pixel](http://lorempixel.com/)
This generates placeholder images for your html if the specified size. The url of the site follows the pattern : `http://lorempixel.com/[width]/[height]/[category(optional)]/[number(optional)]/`

An example of this is: [400 by 200px sports image](http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/)

If you are using brackets, it comes with an extension for this, so that you can set the requirements in UI, and it gives you the URL of the image.

> **No more spending hours on searching throwaway images!!**